# Как исправить парсер

Tags: python, парсер

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_html(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.text

def get_all_links(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

    tds = soup.find('div', class_='kraslep4').find_all('div', class_='kraslep5')

    links = []

    for td in tds:
        a = td.find('a').get('href')
        links.append(a)

    return links


def main():
    url = 'https://uchebniki-rabochie-tetradi.com/knijka1812listat/num1812.html'
    all_links = get_all_links(get_html(url))

    for i in all_links:
        print(i)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Код выше парсер сайта https://uchebniki-rabochie-tetradi.com/knijka1812listat/num1812.html, мне нужно получить ссылки на каждое фото и объединить все jpg, которые я получу в один файл или документ, чтобы получилось как единая книга (или что то подобное, может даже в pdf).

И тут я столкнулся с двумя проблемами: Во-первых, у меня при запуске кода выводится всего одна ссылка, на первую страницу, предполагаю это потому что нужно как-то изменить  `tds = soup.find('div', class_='kraslep4').find_all('div', class_='kraslep5')` в функции get_all_links, но это мой первый парсер и я мало знаком с библиотекой requests.

Во-вторых помогите найти направление куда двигаться, чтобы сделать из всех ссылок единый документ или pdf.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_all_links(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

    tds = soup.find_all('div', class_='kraslep5')
        links = []

    for td in tds:
        a = td.find('a').get('href')
        links.append(a)

    return links
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]